# Are there any probabilistic models for graph-based recommender systems?

Tags: probability, modeling, predictive-models, recommender-system, graph-theory

All I can find now is somehow based on random walks or graph kernels, which is nice, but I want to have a more or less solid probabilistic foundation for my recommender system for bounds and estimations and stuff which usually comes with probabilistic models.

I probably should clarify: I have a graph and want to build recommender engine what recommends certain vertexes based on the ones selected by user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [very-well](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.de/2010/09/icann-netflix-with-neural-networks-and.html) known approach based on restricted BOltzmann machines (RBM), which won the Netflix competition. For more details you may have a look at the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine) site, and the references therein.

Restricted Boltzmann machines are a particular instance of Markov Random Fields, with some properties that makes particularly attractive. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61435/energy-function-of-rbm/61460#61460) a couple of points are made.

The approach is described in detail in this [paper](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2007_SalakhutdinovMH07.pdf). The idea is that there is a RBM per user. Each RBM has as many hidden units as items rated by the user. The main insight is weight sharing: the weight referring to a corresponding item is shared by all users, i.e. it is the same parameter. So when many users give a good rating to an item, the corresponding weight becomes stronger for all users. And viceversa. Here is where collaboration takes place.

Now, in order to see what items to recommend to a given user, one clamp the visible units to the observed ratings, and evaluates the probability of obtaining a given rating for each user. You may have a look at these [slides](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/dme/studpres0910/Rbm_CF.pdf), where it is graphically explained in more detail.

As I understand, selecting a vertex would be equivalent to selecting one of the items. The RBM would give you back how likely will the user rate the item as k, where k is each of the possible ratings.

Comment: I probably should clarify: I have a graph and want to build recommender engine what recommends certain vertexes based on the ones selected by user.  Any pointers on how to adjust RBM or MRF to the task? I would appreciate a link to a good paper or even better handbook.

Comment: Another option, also mentioned in the paper is pLSA (su-2010-projekt.googlecode.com/svn.../hoffman2003collaborative.pdf‎). Is easier to implement, and factors are easier to interpret

Comment: What do you thing would be better model for data without numerical ratings?

Comment: What do you mean by not numerical ratings? It is only assumed that the ratings can be represented by categorical variable, i.e. the ratings are represented a discrete set of elements. So you could apply any of them.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you. Going to give it some more thought...

Comment: You should mention that with RBMs it is in general not possible to evaluate $p(x)$, since it's intractable. Only the free energy $\mathcal{F}(x) = \log p(x) + const$ can be calculated. The OP seems to be interested in this feature.

Answer (score 2):

There is another good [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/69521/gunawardana08__tied_boltz_machin_cold_start_recom.pdf) on this for unrestricted Boltzmann machines. You might also look at [sum/max product networks](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sum%20product%20discrimitive&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/nips12.pdf&ei=BBkqU___AePd0QHy6YHgDA&usg=AFQjCNFoxpHvaTqgybv0T4F_TnNzYRwSOw&sig2=PooId_8s02_2_0BDeERwtw&bvm=bv.62922401,d.dmQ).

It may be that what you really want to do is compute marginal distributions rather than a real recommendation systems. In that case consider Markov Random Fields or perhaps log-linear models.